# jQuery: how to go through multiple objects and make an attribute the same as the item's title?

Tags: jquery, list, reference, title, cycle

I have the following structure:

```
<a title="title 1"> T1 </a>
<a title="title 2"> T2 </a>
...
<a title="title n"> Tn </a>
```

What I need to do is set the `data-filter` attribute in each `a` to the same value as the title, to get this:

```
<a title="title 1" data-filter="title 1"> T1 </a>
<a title="title 2" data-filter="title 2"> T2 </a>
....
<a title="title n" data-filter="title n"> Tn </a>
```

So I was trying something like this:

```
$("a").attr("data-filter", $(this).attr("title"));
```

My problem is with the `$(this)` part. I'm trying to reference the current element to use the `title`. How can I do this? Thank you.

Comment: Why do you need the attribute, when it's (obviously and necessarily) available as a property of the DOM node itself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're close.  `$(this)` only works when you're in a function.  In your case, you want to use `$(this)` in a function that iterates through all the elements your selector finds, using [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/):

```
$("a").each(function() { $(this).attr("data-filter", $(this).attr("title")) });
```

Here's a basic [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/d2pps/).

Comment: There's no need to 'use jQuery' to retrieve the `title` property, when it's easily (and 'more-cheaply') available as a property of the DOM node.

Comment: Did you forget the `function` in `.each` or is this new in jQuery?

Comment: @Vega I forgot.  Thanks for the catch, I've fixed it.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to jQuery and I'm still learning about all these details.

Answer (score 6):

Try using the function arg version of the `.attr` function,

http://api.jquery.com/attr/#attr-attributeName-functionindex--attr

```
$("a").attr("data-filter", function () {
    return this.title;
});
```